# AD LDS schema master role change in a cluster

Tags: active-directory

I have servers which hold AD LDS server role and each of them has schema master role. How could I configure them to have only one schema master and others as replica ? (without server shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pardon me, but ... you mean FSMO roles?

You have 2 servers and each of them has FSMO roles? Because there is only one schema master role in an AD environment (*the 5 FSMOs are : schema, infrastructure, PDC Emulator, domain naming master, and RID Master* ).

*If you are following best practice*, the Schema & Domain Naming Master roles will be on **one** DC, and then Infrastructure, PDC, and RID Master will be on **another**. You can transfer all the roles onto one server, but .. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that per se because that means if one DC Went down you'd lose all your FSMO Roles and your AD environment would essentially cease to function.

Comment: Yes, I mean the FSMO role. In case of the master server, which has the FSMO role is gone, I would like to automatically select other server to have this role in order to have the sync between the other AD LDS replicas.